# SQLAlchemy column synonym with different type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using the SQLAlchemy recipe [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/types.html#marshal-json-strings) to magically JSON encode/decode a column from the DB in my model like:

```
class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'things'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    data = Column(JSONEncodedDict)
```

I hit a snag when I wanted to create an extra "raw_data" field in my model to access the same underlying JSON data, but without encoding/decoding it:

```
    raw_data = Column("data", VARCHAR)
```

SQLAlchemy seems to get confused by the name collision and leave one column un-mapped. Is there any way I can convince SQLAlchemy to actually map both attributes to the same column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just define the `raw_data` column through SQLAlchemy and then use Python's property/setter to make transparent use of `data`. I.e.:

```
class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'things'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    raw_data = Column(String())

    @property
    def data(self):
        # add some checking here too
        return json.loads(self.raw_data)

    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        # dito
        self.raw_data = json.dumps(value)
```

Comment: There are 2 problems: 1) it doesn't handle in-place mutations properly, 2) JSON is parsed for each attribute access.

Comment: @Denis: The in-place mutation tracking is almost orthogonal. I've been tinkering with it, and there's much more to it than the example in the docs implies: https://gist.github.com/1730610 .

Comment: @DenisOtkidach, the second problem is easily solved by caching yourself. It's sort of premature optimization though so I didn't include it immediately. I don't have a ton of experience with SQLAlchemy in particular but from what I gather this solution is not an uncommon approach.

Comment: @Denis: This does sound like the best way to handle my case (possibly with some mutation tracking and/or caching mixed in). Sounds like the answer to my more general question, whether you can have two types on a field, is that SQLAlchemy isn't designed to work that way explicitly and you should always use a property like this.